# Difference between Sting.map and String.mapi in OCaml

Tags: string, ocaml

Difference between `Sting.map` and `String.mapi` in OCaml. The guide says the the former "applies the function" while the latter "calls the function"? What does that mean? I also tried this:

```
String.map (fun x -> Char.uppercase_ascii x) "lala";;
```

and it works. But if I try it with

```
String.mapi (fun x -> Char.uppercase_ascii x) "lala";;
```

I get

```
Error: This expression has type int but an expression was expected of type char
```

Which doesn't make sense to me because I though the error should be the other way around. How should I think about `String.mapi`?

Comment: Read the full sentence: "`String.mapi f s` calls `f` with each character of `s` **and its index** (in increasing index order) and stores the results in a new string that is returned." Emphasis mine. From the type signature you should (eventually) also be able to see that the function is expected to have the type `int -> char -> char`, that is, it takes two arguments, the first being the index and the second being the character.

Comment: What does it mean to "call" function f? Does it mean that it applies a function and hte function needs to have two arguments, one for index, one for character? What is the point of this function String.mapi?

Comment: "Calls" and "applies" means the same thing, that it will run the function for each character in the string, and its associated index. The point of `mapi` vs `map` is to also get the index, as `map` will only call the function with the character.

Comment: For example, `let f i x = if (i = 3) then x else '_' in mapi f "abcdef"` gives `"___d__"`; how much useful it is in practice I don't know, but that's a possible way to use it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference between terms *calls* and *applies* in the context of OCaml documentation. The main difference between those two functions is that `String.map` passes to the user function only one argument, the character, as the input, where `String.mapi` passes to the user function two arguments -- the position of the character (starting from zero) and the character itself.